# How do I Lock an Interaction Volume After use

Tags: rec-room

After i use the interaction volume, i want it to be disabled so that it cant be used again, unless you click a reset button.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Interaction Volume" to be "Locked" (True) will disable it from being able to be interacted with (the default is False which allows the interaction).

Can use the Interaction Volume directly or use the cv2 "Interaction Volume Set Locked" chip.